# How to connect Java application with system web-browsers?

Tags: java, url, browser

I want to connect my java application to the system web browsers (regardless which and how many browsers exist).

All I want is when my application is running any URL the user trying to reach via any browser in the system must be captured by my application. How can i do that with java? and if it possible but with connecting it to libraries or other API's it's OK with me.

p.s. i'll run this application on **Windows** only.

Answer (score 2):

```
try{     
    java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OS, this will vary, such as on Windows `start http://www.example.com` will open the browser, where as in OSX, you have to do a `open http://www.example.com`. These are the system commands that you would have to invoke from Java.

Comment: *"Depending on the OS, this will vary,"*  There is a J2SE method for it.  See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can rather create a Web Browser using cross-platform support:
All you need is:

- A user interface api such as AWT and Swing
- A net API(java.net)
- File and stream handling API(java.io)

All these are available in J2SE library, but you will need some additional apis such as HTML renderers api. In android use WebKit

Comment: Y U SO ANGRY AND LOUDS